# QuaternionToHopfCoordinate origin of formula in drake

Tags: math, drake

I have a question regarding the functionality of QuaternionToHopfCoordinate in the drake library (https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/math/hopf_coordinate.h).
While the used formulas for HopfCoordinateToQuaternion are found in the corresponding paper, the implemented formula for QuaternionToHopfCoordinate is not presented. Could you please provide an explanation how one arrives at this formula? Are there any assumptions for that input?

I implemented the function in Python and checked the validity of the formulas with several examples.
For example, with the original quaternion q=[w,x,y,z]=[-0.2698726 , -0.0122792 , 0.1635996 , 0.94881672], the mapping QuaternionToHopfCoordinate(HopfCoordinateToQuaternion(q)) does not result in the original quaternion. (It does result in the same quaternion for HopfCoordinateToQuaternion(-q) = -q. So, the Hopf coordinates for q and -q are not the equivalent, but differ for the phi angle by pi.)

Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the problem! I confirm there is a bug in our code. Working on a fix.

Comment: The bug is fixed in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/18747.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the bug fix!
For academic purpose: Could you please provide a reference on how you derived this formula? Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: I derived the equation manually, sorry I don’t know a reference